# How to detect if there is an incoming sms from GSM modem in c#

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

I want to create a C# application that will automatically detect incoming SMS. It will process the message in that SMS and resend something to that same number the SMS came from. I can successfully send and receive SMS but cannot make program to automatically detect SMS and process it. The code I developed works only for few SMS then it stops working. What is wrong in this code and if there is another better way to do this?

in this code I cal `runTimer()`..

```
public void RunEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int uCountSMS = objclsSMS.CountSMSmessages(port);
        if (uCountSMS > 0)
        {
            objShortMessageCollection = objclsSMS.ReadSMS(this.port, strCommand);
            foreach (ShortMessage msg in objShortMessageCollection)
            {
                if (msg.Sender == "+923007302422")
                {
                    //    this.textBox1.Text = "no";
                    if (msg.Message == "code")
                    {

                        objclsSMS.sendMsg(this.port, "any number", "good");

                    }
                    else if (msg.Message == "hi")
                    {
                        objclsSMS.sendMsg(this.port, "anynumber", "bye");

                    }

                    //     objclsSMS.DeleteMsg(this.port, "AT+CMGD=1,3");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
    }
}  

public void runTimer()
{
    try
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);

        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RunEvent);
        //    aTimer.Interval = 3000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```